# Read Level/Transaction Levels for Access 2010

Tags: database, ms-access

A friend is the network admin at a non-profit. This company stores their account data in an Access database that they've placed on a server. This server has access granted to several members (the accounts team), whom will sometimes concurrently make updates to the database.

This has resulted in lost and incorrect data being entered. I explained to my friend that this was likely due to the Access read level not being set to a transaction level equivalent to 'Isolated', and that the concurrent users were overwriting the Access versions. I also told my friend that Access is typically not used for semi-production level work, and that MySQL would be an alternative option if the company wanted a free database system that they could build onto and start performing SQL-type tasks.

So, my question is singular:

1. Is there a transaction-level setting that will prevent overwrites and data loss in Access?

Comment: Consider using a managed MySQL deployment, if practical. Try Amazon RDS.

Comment: Does the Access database use a split front-end/back-end (FE/BE) architecture, i.e., a front-end file (Forms, Queries, etc.) and a back-end file (Tables only)?

Comment: I'm unsure of the architecture, but from the description it's merely an Access database put on the network that multiple people access with a user-friendly form that multiple users do data entry on. It apparently doesn't have any kind of current version control or transaction-level control.

Comment: Access isn't so poor that it can't cope with this scenario...something else must be wrong. By default it should cope with a few people using it concurrently from a network share.

Comment: If multiple concurrent users are directly opening the *same copy* of an `.mdb` or `.accdb` file on a network share then that could definitely lead to strange errors (and possible data loss). Multi-user Access databases **must** be split into front-end and back-end files and each user **must** have their own local copy of the front-end file. (The common back-end data file obviously remains in the shared folder on the server.)

Comment: I suspect that must be what's happening - your description matches the framework that my friend described. I'll pass the information on, and many thanks! I'll also suggest that the company try splitting the front-end and back-end into two distinct files, and share out the front-end (application) portion to the users in charge of data entry.